# Create Increment Counter Everytime Running A Job In Talend Using tMap

Tags: database, postgresql, triggers, talend

I Would like to ask how to create a specific counter every row if i run a job in Talend Data Integration when using tMap components

For Example, this is a result in which there are 5 data in every row  has 0 counter

Table Animal
Animal Counter 
Zebra 0 
Zebra 0 
Zebra 0 
Zebra 0 
Zebra 0

When i run a job using tMap, i want the final result like this

Table Animal: Final Results 
Animal Counter 
Zebra 0 
Zebra 0 
Zebra 0 
Zebra 0 
Zebra 0 
Zebra 1 
Zebra 1 
Zebra 1 
Zebra 1 
Zebra 1

Every time i run a job, the field on counter always increment by one and data always inserted

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The two options I see are:

1. use a context variable stored in a file. You'll need to load this file before each job and update it before finishing. in the Tmap it would look something like this: Integer.parseInt(context.Counter) + 1
2. Assuming you are loading your records into a database, perform a lookup on the max counter value and assign that to a variable in the TMap

Comment: select animal, max(counter)+1 from final result  then tMap it.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to show you an alternative to do what you look for.

Instead of tMap use, I'm using a tJavaRow component, the result will be the same as you as asking for, but achieved with java code.

The job's reading from a .csv trhough a tFileInputDelimited, which has got the next [data](https://photos.app.goo.gl/UF5ABezjLvKR5q5j7).

Following you will see a tJavaRow component where inside is the java code, and finally a tlogRow component to show the final dataset. - [Job Image](https://photos.app.goo.gl/3a6p1kiBvc6ntQMM8) -

> Code Inside tJavaRow

```
output_row.Animal = input_row.Animal; /*Code generated according to input schema and output schema*/
if (context.counter == -1){ /*Conditional to hold just the first row interaction*/

    context.counter=0; /*Initialization of the context variable (Counter)*/
    output_row.Counter = context.counter;
    context.previousRecord = row1.Animal; /*Store the previous animal name*/

}else{ /*the java thread execution takes this way after the first interaction*/

      if(row1.Animal.equals(context.previousRecord)){ /*compare the actual animal (row1.Animal) vs the previous one*/

          output_row.Counter = context.counter;
          context.previousRecord = row1.Animal;
      }else{

          context.counter++;
          output_row.Counter = context.counter;
          context.previousRecord = row1.Animal;
      }
}
```

Here you've got [the image of the final result](https://photos.app.goo.gl/WuePi8CmBe9vv12a6) !

\(ToT)/